# Optimization Bundles and Umbraco 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've recently setup a hybrid Umbraco 4.8 webforms + mvc application (see aaron powell's post on this: http://www.aaron-powell.com/umbraco/using-mvc-in-umbraco-4)

I have everything working great. I even configured ninject and I'm using MVC4 optimization bundles. The problem is that when I try to enable optimizations the dynamic routes are getting picked up by the umbraco url rewriter and I can't render CSS or JS files in the release configuration.

This renders fine (since it's a static route):
`http://myserverUrl/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.js`

This doesn't:`http://myserverUrl/js/combined?v=J_D8qmUMMTWvtIuuef2sskA8d2JCiGB9kNZMq_nNKpw1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Umbraco handles all the request, that aren't to a static file, so you need to configure Umbraco to skip those pathes

In web.config put "~/js" as a reserved url, just as you have done to the route you made.

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/js" />
```